# Modbus ascii communication

Tags: python, modbus

I'm trying to send a command to my sensor and get the response back, but I'm facing these problems:

1. The time elapsed between each received/saved data is not exactly 1 second
2. The program stops printing/saving data after a few iterations, even though the code is still running

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import serial
import time
import os

# Create a directory with the desired name format
folder_name = time.strftime("%H%M%S%d%m%y")
os.makedirs(folder_name, exist_ok=True)

# Establish serial connection
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 19200, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)

# Save column headers to the file
file_path = os.path.join(folder_name, "data.txt")
with open(file_path, "a") as file:
file.write("date_time\telapsed_seconds\tO2_ppm\tO2_percent\n")

start_time = time.time()

try:
while True:
# Send MODBUS command to read O2 ppm
ser.write(b':010400000004F7\r\n')
response = ser.readline().decode().strip()
print(response)

o2_ppm = float(response[7:15]) / 100.0 # Adjust according to the format mentioned
print(o2_ppm)

o2_percent = o2_ppm / 10000
print(o2_percent)

# Calculate elapsed seconds
elapsed_seconds = time.time() - start_time

# Get current timestamp
timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Append data to the file
with open(file_path, "a") as file:
file.write(f"{timestamp}\t{elapsed_seconds:.2f}\t{o2_ppm:.2f}\t{o2_percent:.6f}\n")

time.sleep(1) # Wait for 1 second

except KeyboardInterrupt:
pass

finally:
# Close the serial connection
ser.close()
```

Please give me some suggestions to rectify the issue. Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to send a command to my sensor and get the response back, but I'm facing these problems:

1. The time elapsed between each received/saved data is not exactly 1 second
2. The program stops printing/saving data after a few iterations, even though the code is still running

Comment: Your code is incorrect due to the indentation not being valid.

Comment: Regarding your first issue, you're sleeping for exactly one second between each iteration. But sending the command and processing the response takes time as well, so of course the total time of each iteration is more than one second (e.g. if processing takes about 300ms then each itearation will take roughly 1.3s). A simple fix is to calculate the runtime of the iteration and subtract that from your sleep amount. That will still have an error in the low ms range, for anything more precise you would need a more sophisticated scheduling solution.